multiple SecurityFilterChain always returns the same error
I'm encountering an issue with my Spring Security configuration, where the request paths seem to always match the first SecurityFilterChain, despite my use of the u/Order annotation.
Here is the relevant code snippet:
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain apiKeySecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .securityMatcher("/api/notifications/**")  // Only matches notifications paths
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(apiKeyAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain jwtSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .securityMatcher("/api/**")  // Matches all other API paths
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()  // Allow access to auth paths
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()              // Authenticate all other requests
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
}

@Component
public class ApiKeyAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    …
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        String requestApiKey = request.getHeader("X-API-KEY");
        String requestApiSecret = request.getHeader("X-API-SECRET");
        // Validate the key and secret
        if (apiKey.equals(requestApiKey) && apiSecret.equals(requestApiSecret)) {
            // Continue processing the request
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
            response.getWriter().write("Unauthorized test");
        }
    }
}

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ...
    }
}

From Spring Security, I should be able to have multiple SecurityFilterChains.

Issue:
No matter what path I use for my requests, they always seem to be routed to the apiKeySecurityFilterChain (Order 1). I expected that requests to paths not matching "/api/notifications/**" would be handled by jwtSecurityFilterChain (Order 2), but this isn't happening.
So, whenever request path I send, it always returns error "Unauthorized test"
Application Log - not sure if its related
2024-10-03T14:33:20.340-07:00 DEBUG 75740 --- [backend] [nio-8005-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /auth/login/app
2024-10-03T14:33:20.346-07:00 DEBUG 75740 --- [backend] [nio-8005-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-10-03T14:33:20.346-07:00 DEBUG 75740 --- [backend] [nio-8005-exec-1] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Request requested invalid session id 8F392A25E730ADD3CD98B2175C2693B5

What I tried
1st
I tried to comment out
  .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) 

in jwtSecurityFilterChain, and it finally not returns "Unauthorized test". I am wondering if it's because of both filter uses @Overide for method doFilterInternal?
2nd
The weird thing is, I try to comment end the method apiKeySecurityFilterChain, but it still gives me the same error "Unauthorized test" even though apiKeyAuthFilter doesn't apply.
//@Order(1)
//public SecurityFilterChain apiKeySecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception //{
//    return http
//            .securityMatcher("/api/notifications/**")  // Only matches notifications //paths
//           .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
//           .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> //httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
//            .sessionManagement(session -> //session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
//            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
//            .addFilterBefore(apiKeyAuthFilter, //UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
//          .build();
//}

@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain jwtSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .securityMatcher("/api/**")  // Matches all other API paths
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()  // Allow access to auth paths
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()              // Authenticate all other requests
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
}

Even more weird, with the same code above, the error disappear when I comment out
The entire filter class below
// All commented out
//@Component
//public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  //  ...
  //  @Override
  //  protected void doFilterInternal(
  //          @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
 //           @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
 //           @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
 //   ) throws ServletException, IOException {
 //       ...
 //   }
//}

Question
What could be causing this routing issue in my Spring Security configuration, and how can I ensure that requests are correctly routed to the appropriate SecurityFilterChain based on their path?

why have you built custom homemade security with jwtAuthenticationFilter? there is a reason spring security does not include such a filter per default, the password token flow is deprecated and deemed insecure. So why ask about something that is dangerous, is this security research?
